# How to Display Conditional Plain Text with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having issues with displaying (rather NOT displaying) plain text in an else block.

```
if (Model.CareerFields != null && ViewBag.CFCount > 0)
{
<h3>Careerfields Listing</h3>

<table>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Careerfield Name</th>
   </tr>

   @foreach (var item in Model.CareerFields)
   {
       <tr>
       <td>
          @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { careerFieldID = item.CareerFieldId })
       </td>
       <td>
          @item.CareerFieldName
       </td>
       </tr>
   }
   </table>
}
else
{
  No Careerfields associated with @ViewBag.SelectedDivisionTitle
}
```

The if blocks works fine. The text only renders when true. However, the else block text renders when the page loads, not if it evaluates to false only.

I've tried using

```
Hmtl.Raw("No Careerfields associated with ")
<text>No Careerfields associated with @ViewBag.SelectedDivisionTitle</text>
@:No Careerfields associated with @ViewBag.SelectedDivisionTitle
```

But it still renders the plaintext before evaluation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of only else use "else if" to solve your display issue

Comment: Have you tried using <text></text>?  like this: <text>No Careerfields associated with @ViewBag.SelectedDivisionTitle</text>

Comment: @user1304444 Yes, I have. It does not work.

Comment: @swapneel doesn't work either. It's processing everything after the initial if.

Comment: What about this slight change?  `<text>No Careerfields associated with </text> @ViewBag.SelectedDivisionTitle`  If that still doesn't work, I think I would take the `@Viewbag.SelectedDivisionTitle` completely out (just to see what it does).  Maybe it's causing razor to not understand where html ends and C# begins.

Comment: Also, maybe look for unterminated html tags further up in your view.  They might mess up the Razor syntax.

Answer (score 14):

Put your "plain text" inside of a naked `<span>` tag:

```
else
{
  <span>No Careerfields associated with @ViewBag.SelectedDivisionTitle</span>
}
```

The browser shouldn't render it special (unless you have css selecting every span) and it'll help razor sense the end of the C# and print your HTML.

Comment: It is still rendering. No CSS on span tags - I am just using the default stylesheet right now that is created with an MVC3 app.

Answer (score 14):

The following code worked perfectly for me:

```
@if (false) {
    <h3>
        Careerfields Listing
    </h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
                Careerfield Name
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
else 
{ 
    @:No Careerfields associated with @ViewBag.SelectedDivisionTitle
}
```

You can see that the contents of **if** are rendered when you change condition to **true**.

Comment: Thank you so much, only adding @: before the text works for me

Comment: Thanks for the example. I tried to put it all on one line and it didn't work. The layout you'w shown made my day.

Answer (score 8):

The most concise and correct answer is:

###### Prepend `@:` before the text.

*(note the `:` after the `@`)*

This still allows to embed variables in the text by prepending an `@` to the variable name:

```
@if (someCondition)
{
   @:Some text you want to see.
}
else
{
   @:Some other text, with a variable @someVariable included in the text.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've forgotten the `@` sign before your `if` statement. Try this:

```
@if (Model.CareerFields != null && ViewBag.CFCount > 0)
{
    <h3>Careerfields Listing</h3>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Careerfield Name</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.CareerFields)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { careerFieldID = item.CareerFieldId })
                </td>
                <td>@item.CareerFieldName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
else
{
    <text>No Careerfields associated with @ViewBag.SelectedDivisionTitle</text>
}
```